# How to define different behaviour for different radio buttons - Java's SWT

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

Consider the following code:

```
public class SWTTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Display display=new Display();
        Shell shell=new Shell(display, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);

        Group group=new Group(shell, SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_OUT);
        group.setText("A group");

        Button[] options=new Button[2];
        options[0]=new Button(group, SWT.RADIO);
        options[0].setText("Option 1");
        options[0].setLocation(5, 20);
        options[0].pack();

        options[1]=new Button(group, SWT.RADIO);
        options[1].setText("Option 2");
        options[1].setLocation(5, 50);
        options[1].pack();

        options[0].addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Option 1 Selected");                
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });


        group.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) 
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

My intention is that whenever option 1 is selected, the `widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)` method will be invoked, and **only** then, but the problem is that selecting option 2 **also** invokes the `widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)` method, even though I didn't submit option 2 as a listener, nor I implemented the `widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)` method for it.
So what's going on here, and how can I define different behavior for different option selection?

---

#### Edit

Oh... and one more thing...
what if I am not interested in implementing the widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) method?  Should I just leave it that way?

Comment: Extend `SelectionAdapter` to get a default implementation of `widgetDefaultSelected`.

Comment: I think that your `SelectionListener` will get fired when something is *deselected* as well.  Your listener(s) should query the state of the radio buttons instead of assuming that an event indicates their state.

Comment: Yup. that was it. changed it to listen to mouse clicks instead. thank you both for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ***Edward Thomson*** mentionned it in the comments, a *SelectionEvent*  is fired on the *Button* **selection** as well as its **de-selection**.

Your *EventListener* should check for the *Button* status :

```
button.getSelection() // return true if the button is selected
```

this is how I usually do it:

```
Button button = new Button(parent , SWT.RADIO);
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter(){
    @override
    public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e){
        super.widgetSelected();
        if(button.getSelection()){
            //do your processing
        }
    }
});
```